# Can I use bullets and sections in a teaching statement?

Tags: teaching-statement

My question is: Can you write your teaching statement so that it is divided into parts with bullet items and sections (without writing paragraphs and lots of texts).

Here is an example of a teaching statement:

> ```
>                                 Teaching Statement
>
>                                       Dr. XY
>           
>                                   May 12th, 2021
> ```
>
> **Teaching Pedagogy**
>
> My pedagogy in teaching is as follows:
>
> - I opt for a student-centric approach
> - I use interactive presentation
> - ...
>
> **Teaching Methodology**
>
> My methodology in teaching is as follows:
>
> - Prepare for each lecture;
> - Define clearly the objective of each lecture;
> - ...
>
> **Teaching Experience**
>
> During my past experience, I taught several classes, including:
>
> - CLASS1: ...
> - CLASS2: ...

Comment: Sure you can. This is a good idea! Do it!

Comment: I would hate it if I was on the search committee, because I want to see narrative explaining why you teach the way you do, specifically tying your practice to your philosophy.  Others might like it.

Comment: My own teaching statement is bulleted, but each bullet is a short paragraph.  As a member of a search committee, I would rather see more details about some specific things that you do than a long list of very vague things.

Comment: On further thought, I'm voting to close as 'opinion-based' - there are no answers other than the opinions of potential search committee members (who have reasons for their preferences), which will vary wildly.

Comment: I would expect they would want to see some actual meat on those bullet points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking the wrong question. The right question is "How do I best convey the information I want to present?". If bullet points is the best way to do so, then Yes! you should be using those, regardless of whether this is for a teaching statement, a research paper, a grant application, or a newspaper article. On the other hand, if bullet points are *not* the best way to do this, then you shouldn't be using them wherever it is that you are tempted to do so.

*How* you typeset things should not be dictated by some abstract rules that are defined and kept my some monks in a monastery at the top of a mountain surrounded by a desert. Instead, how you explain things should be dictated by *what is the best way for you to explain things to your audience*.